# Unable to upload Chinook DB on APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

Is there a way to upload and import the Chinook DB into Oracles' APEX. I downloaded the db file from the chinook website (https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/)  but having trouble finding how to upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got it wrong. [Chinook documentation](https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create_Databases&referringTitle=Documentation) page suggests that - once you download the file and extract ZIP contents into some directory - you have to connect to SQL*Plus in order to perform installation.

It says that you should create a database user (which means that you have to have access to that database as a privileged user, such as SYS). Then you'd create objects and insert data into tables.

Therefore, Apex comes far, far in the future (regarding your current position). Besides, I'd say that it is YOU who should create an Apex application based on Chinook database; you won't get *anything* Apex-ish during Chinook installation.

Comment: Thanks for the info Littlefoot. I will do that then.